# Transfer-Encoding: chunked not handled by Chrome

Tags: http, google-chrome, tomcat, http-headers

I'm running a web application using Tomcat 7. The app is returning everyone's favorite HTTP header, `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. When I navigate to the root url with Chrome (and Firefox, fwiw), Chrome only downloads the first 16384 bytes of the resource. The resource is definitely larger than that size. Why is Chrome only fetching the initial chunk? I see this when accessing the resource with curl:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9C7D0EE5D26AD7C99551204CE2896422; Path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 03 Dec 2013 23:07:09 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

(I know there are several questions on this topic, but they seem to involve disabling `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. I want to know why Chrome isn't handling the situation correctly.)

Comment: The example you give doesn't seem to use chunked encoding in the payload (just declaring it isn't sufficient :-)

Comment: It's not being "declared" anywhere, unless the default install of Tomcat 7 "declares" that somehow. Perhaps I was wrong to trust that it would be configured sanely out of the box...

Comment: cbmanica: it's declared in the response header fields that you posted

Comment: If Tomcat feels that it can take it upon itself to send `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and simultaneously not send actual chunk-encoded data, then it seems to be much more useless than I suspected.

Comment: cbmanica: code example? what are you doing?

Comment: I missed an exception in the log - guess something is blowing up Tomcat mid-transfer for some reason.